# Decorating all methods of a class

Tags: ruby

Say I have a class `Caller` that calls another class's methods (i.e. `Abc`) in ruby:

```
class Caller
    def run
        abc = Abc.new
        abc.method1
        abc.method2
    end
end

class Abc
   def method1
      puts 'Method1 etc'
   end
   def method2
      puts 'Method2 etc'
   end
end

caller = Caller.new
caller.run
```

Any time a method in class `Abc` is called, I need to decorate the call with a prefix that shows the `Calling` method class name and method name
E.g. in the example above, I need the following output:

```
Caller.run - Method1 etc
Caller.run - Method2 etc
```

What is the best way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create decorator that will not define any particular method, but will implement `method_missing` hook, and wrap every call in whatever code you need:

```
class Caller
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    puts 'wrapper'
    @object.public_send(meth, *args, &block)
  end
end

class YourClass
  def method1
    puts "method 1"
  end
end

c = Caller.new(YourClass.new)

c.method1
```

This way your decorator is unobtrusive. Moreover you can control which method calls are wrapped (e.g. by defining whitelist or blacklist in `method_missing`). This is quite clear way of defining **aspects** of behavior in well separated blocks of code.

Comment: this is more of a proxy isn't it? anyway activesupport provides `ActiveSupport::BasicObject` as a base class to build proxies. worth looking into

Comment: This is pure-ruby approach. There is also `SimpleDelegator` in stdlib, that could serve similar purpose.

Comment: As of difference between proxy and delegator pattern -- these naming conventions come from statically typed languages, where they had to be implemented completely different. Ruby flexible typing system makes many of these patterns obsolete, as identical behavior can be implemented in many ways.

Comment: i often use activesupport without rails, the thing is with `BasicObject` you don't have to `undef` all the methods that you inherit from `Object`.

Comment: @MarianTheisen BasicObject is part of [Ruby Core 1.9](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/BasicObject.html).